# Que veut dire « la tête en arrière » ?

Tags: sens, paroles-de-chanson

Le groupe Luke a sorti un album intitulé *La tête en arrière*.
Dans cet album, il y a une chanson, *Soledad* qui comporte dans [ses paroles](http://musique.ados.fr/Luke/Soledad-t379.html) « La tête en arrière ».  J'ai aussi entendu ces paroles dans une autre chanson par un autre groupe.

Est-ce que c'est un idiome, ou est-ce que ça veut dire littéralement « *backwards head* », « *head thrown back* », etc. ?  Même avec la traduction littérale, je ne suis pas tout à fait sûr de ce que ça veut dire en anglais.

Comment: Je ne connais que le sens littéral, et je ne vois pas non plus ce qu'il vient faire là.

Comment: Je peux ajouter au commentaire de Gilles que *Soledad* est *solitude* en espagnol, et que les wikipédiant, ils ont l'air de faire pas mal de trucs proche de l'espagnol, mais je ne vois rien non plus de pertinent par là (avec *cabeza hacia atrás*).

Comment: Au registre des explications improbables, on peut concevoir une espèce d'opposition par rapport à *aller de l'avant* et *marcher en tête*, qui sous-entendrait qu'ils sont à l'avant-garde, mais de l'autre côté, comme s'ils prenaient le contre-pied de quelque chose. Plus fumeux, tu meurs ? Oui oui.

Comment: @Gilles Donc, la meilleur expression est « head tilted backward » qui veut dire que la figure pointe vers le ciel ou que la tête a tourné 180 degrés ou quelque chose d'autre?

Comment: Je ne pense pas que ça soit traduisible si tu ne sais pas ce qu'ils veulent dire par là, *tête* peut vouloir dire beaucoup de choses (*lead*, *face*), et littéralement, ça ne veut surtout pas dire grand chose. Ça pourrait être une référence à *tête en l'air*, aussi (pour *distrait*).

Comment: Honnêtement je ne suis pas sûr que ça veuille dire grand-chose. Luke est assez célèbre pour ses paroles assez peu sensées.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Il existe aussi [un roman](http://www.evene.fr/livres/livre/nathalie-de-broc-la-tete-en-arriere-40912.php?critiques#critique-evene) de Nathalie de Broc dont le titre est *La tête en arrière*. D'après quelques critiques et commentaires sur ce livre, la tête en arrière symbolise un sentiment d'angoisse : nous sommes tellement dépassés par certains problèmes que ça provoquerait un recul qui mettrait notre tête en arrière.

Parmi [diverses critiques sur ce livre](http://www.pol-editeur.com/index.php?spec=livre&ISBN=978-2-8180-0298-8), on peut lire : *Page blanche, trou noir. C'est la tête qui part en arrière sous le poids des angoisses.*

En ce qui concerne la chanson de Luke, il est possible que ce soit le même sens, vu les paroles de cette chanson : *Souris ou saigne / Souris aux drames / La tête en arrière / Soledad !*

Cependant, à lire [la critique des Inrocks sur cet album](http://www.lesinrocks.com/musique/critique-album/la-tete-en-arriere/), il se peut aussi que la tête en arrière soit une posture artistique, un peu comme la banane chez les rockers, etc. :

> Brutes, tranchantes, les paroles de Thomas Boulard sont aussi
>   fiévreuses que les mélodies qu’elles escortent. Ici, le jeu de mot est
>   proscrit, les pirouettes linguistiques bannies, le second degré
>   esquivé. Les angles, autrefois arrondis, sont droits, et les têtes (en
>   arrière) au carré. Se démarquant ainsi de la scène française intello [… et blablabla.]